# Only print lines from bottom up if there is data

Tags: java

How would you go about solving the following logic:

I have pdf file with cells:

```
addressLine1
addressLine2
addressLine3
addressLine4
addressLine5
cityStateZip
```

All of them have getters.
Sometimes, all fields have data and sometimes they don't.

To make it pretty, I want them grouped together, ie:

```
1261 Graeber St (address4)
Bldg 2313 Rm 24 (address5)
Pensacola FL 32508 (cityStateZip)
```

You need to account for some of these addresses being blank, if `addressLine1` is the only one existing.ie:

```
1261 Graeber St (address5)
Pensacola FL 32508 (cityStateZip)
```

Here, since `address2`, `address3`, `address4` are blank, we moved `address1` on pdf cell `address5`

My code right now print:

```
1261 Graeber St       (address1)
                      (address2)
                      (address3)
                      (address4)
                      (address5)
Pensacola FL 32508    (cityStateZip)
```

And here is the code:

```
FdfInput.SetValue("addressLine1", getAddressLine1() );
FdfInput.SetValue("addressLine2", getAddressLine2() );
FdfInput.SetValue("addressLine3", getAddressLine3() );
FdfInput.SetValue("addressLine4", getAddressLine4() );
FdfInput.SetValue("addressLine5", getAddressLine5() );
FdfInput.SetValue("addressLine6", getCityStateZip() );
```

Picture on the left is how it looks like right now, I want it to be like picture on the right.

[image]

Is this a good candidate for `LinkedList.insertLast()` ?

Comment: `if (str.isEmpty()) { // don't print }` ??

Comment: Can you show the actual Java you have implemented so far? It'll be easier to build off of what you have.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
if(!getAddressLine1().isEmpty())
    FdfInput.SetValue("addressLine1", getAddressLine1());

if(!getAddressLine2().isEmpty())
    FdfInput.SetValue("addressLine2", getAddressLine2());

if(!getAddressLine3().isEmpty())
    FdfInput.SetValue("addressLine3", getAddressLine3());

if(!getAddressLine4().isEmpty())
    FdfInput.SetValue("addressLine4", getAddressLine4());

if(!getAddressLine5().isEmpty())
    FdfInput.SetValue("addressLine5", getAddressLine5());

if(!getCityStateZip().isEmpty())
    FdfInput.SetValue("cityStateZip", getCityStateZip());
```

In other words, if there is data to add to the line, do so, otherwise, skip it entirely. For example, let's say all of the fields are empty besides address3, address5, and cityStateZip.

```
// The output will not look like this:    


addressLine3

addressLine5
cityStateZip
```

Instead, it will look like:

```
addressLine3
addressLine5
cityStateZip
```

Comment: this will not solve my problem of shifting fields that do exist , downwards.

Comment: Please see my edited answer, now with an example, and tell me why it doesn't work.

Comment: What happens with the Api if you don't call FdfInput.SetValue() on a field that should be empty?  If it just prints an empty cell this solution should work.

Comment: These cells in pdf are fixed, so I have to find a clean way to put addressLine1 value into pdf cell "addressLine5" if all other getters are empty

Comment: So @Angelina, it looks like you actually want the blanks to stay in there, you just want the fields with data to be pushed to the bottom?

Comment: @OmnusRuthius Yes.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by storing strings in array list and decrementing the counter on the name:

```
List<String> addrLines = new ArrayList<String>();

if(!getCityStateZip().isEmpty())
    addrLines.add(getTomaCityStateZip());

if(!getAddressLine5().isEmpty())
    addrLines.add(getAddressLine5());

if(!getAddressLine4().isEmpty())
    addrLines.add(getAddressLine4());

if(!getAddressLine3().isEmpty())
    addrLines.add(getAddressLine3());

if(!getAddressLine2().isEmpty())
    addrLines.add(getAddressLine2());

if(!getAddressLine1().isEmpty())
    addrLines.add(getAddressLine1());

for (int i = addrLines.size(); i > 0; --i)
{
    int line = addrLines.size() - i;
    String field = String.format("addressLine%d", 6 - line);
    FdfInput.SetValue(field, addrLines.get(line));
}
```

Comment: I was looking at this again this morning and came up with something similar and was trying to find a more elegant/dynamic way to do this, but it looks good! I'll post back if I come up with something more efficient later on. 
---Edit: But what happens when the field is called cityStateZip?

Comment: Good question, but I was lucky to have a control over naming pdf cells and decided to call them addressLine1-6